# Best Practices / Approaches for integrating API with Dynamics CRM

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

So we are in the process of starting our integration of our SOAP API with Dynamics using OData. I would like to get some ideas on how other have approached such an integration from a Dynamics perspective.

How do you manage security for Dynamics so that only a specific authorized application, such as the API, can make modifications to Dynamics data?

Similarly, how do you manage views? Do you create a copy of an existing view for everything you want to query or is there a better way?

Are there other considerations that I should be taking into account that others have struggled with in the past?

Comment: What version of CRM? SOAP will be deprecated in the next version so you should use Web API instead.

Comment: Sorry, this is using Dynamics 365. We are using the Web API and OData to connect to Dynamics 365. I suppose our internal API is SOAP, but that is extraneous information, sorry for including that and making things more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some tips for you:

- For the security, you can create a non-interactive user. It's ment to be a service user that can do operation without connecting to the UI. It requires no licence.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/create-users-assign-online-security-roles#create-a-non-interactive-user-account
- Actions can be invoked from Web API and can act as entry-point for external applications. You should use those instead of coding something outside of the CRM.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/actions
- For views, I use the Save As button. When I need to copy views layout I use the XrmToolbox.
  https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/